# undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode while deploying Flask app

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy a Flask app on AWS EC2 running apache2 and mysql on Ubuntu 14.

The flask app needs the following dependencies:

- Pymysql
- Date parser

My app is running fine on my local development machine, but when I try to deploy it, it is giving a 500 internal server error, and my Apache logs are showing the following information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/crimemap/crimemap.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
from crimemap import app as application
File "/var/www/crimemap/crimemap.py", line 5, in <module>
import dateparser
File "/var/www/crimemap/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateparser/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .date import DateDataParser
File "/var/www/crimemap/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 8, in <module>
import regex as re
File "/var/www/crimemap/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/regex.py", line 387, in <module>
import _regex_core
File "/var/www/crimemap/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
import _regex
ImportError: /var/www/crimemap/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_regex.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode
```

P.S.

1. I am using virutalenv, but I am running other Flask apps with virtualenvs on the same server without any problems.
2. My local machine is running Python 2.7.12, the EC2 however, was running 2.7.6, so I was having problems installing dateparser. I installed python 2.7.13 on the EC2 by compiling it from source. Please note that other flask apps using this compiled version of python on the same server are running fine, the only difference is that those apps don't have the dateparser dependency.

Any help would be appreciated.